# in bash/linux: How to create the file text for output completed converted from FFmpeg..?

Tags: text, ffmpeg, find

i don't find in google, how to create file text for output completed from FFmpeg in batch?

example: i find 1000 files old video (.avi) but i want to know what is done completed output example ECHO $files > text.txt.. but i don't find in google or here STACKOVERFLOW..

i use batch in file .sh, there are command FIND, FFMPEG

```
fortmat4find='.avi'
format4output='mp4'
.....
.....
sh -c "find . -iname $format4find -exec ffmpeg -n -i {} {}-CONVERTED$format4output > text.txt \;";
```

result nothing output to text.txt as completed converted..

inside of text.txt will be result like this:

```
./folder1/folder2/AAA.avi-CONVERTED.mp4
./folder4/folder5/AAA.avi-CONVERTED.mp4
....
...
```

i check in guide.. but nothing find information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo

```
#!/bin/bash

format4find=".mkv"
format4output=".mp4"

find . -name "*$format4find" -exec sh -c '
EXT=$1
shift 1
for INP; do
  DUR=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$INP")
  OUT="${INP%.*}-CONVERTED$EXT"
  echo "$DUR $INP $OUT"
  if ffmpeg -n -i "$INP" "$OUT"; then
    echo "$OUT" >> completed.log
  else
    echo "$INP → error" >> error.log
  fi
done' sh $format4output {} +
```

Comment: Баяр Гончикжапов: WOW!!, but i did tested file log.txt result all file converted are ERRORs.. i don't interrupt to ffmpeg (like as completed GOAL..)...

see here result from log.txt:
.avi → error
./AAA.mp4 → error
./Nuova cartella/out-txt.mp4 → error
./Nuova cartella/Nuova cartella/fffrgrggrr.mp4 → error

Comment: that is works, only i fix it: log-completed.txt, log-error.txt thank you , you are awesome!! please can check this other issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709983/how-input-the-file-text-to-ffmpeg-simple-text